# Can we create a WCF service which publishes events?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, spring.net

I want to create a push web application.

The service layer is built on WCF.

The presentation layer is built on Asp.net 4

The service listens to events and updates its static property (a shared collection list) from the data layer.
I am polling in my presentation layer and calling a method of WCF every second and getting the updated collection.

If a collection is unmodified, I return empty list to save network bandwidth.

To save the round trips, I want the WCF service to publish an event if and when the collection is modified.  Is that possible?  How do I achieve this?

Thank you

Comment: You should have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming) , imho WCF Duplex Communication does not work reliable in internet scenarios (you need a direct line of sight between server and client).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

WCF services allows [duplex communication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731064.aspx), so it can send messages to client.

Answer (score 0):

I had been looking for same thing but could not find anything with Push facility in .Net, Then I had to use Flex along with .Net.

You may get start from this [reference](http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_RTMP_Data_Push_from__NET_to_Flex-16983.html)